# Webpack Aliases Working, but Typescript Gives Me Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, tsx

## The problem

I have a project that uses Type Checking for React Components (React-Typescript)

So far, I have configured everything and its working, except for aliases in Typescript.

In webpack, the `module.alias` object allows you to lookup specific folders for the webpack module resolution

```js
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/ts/app.tsx",
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Pedro Uzcátegui',
            template: "./dist/index.html"
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"dist"), 
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env','@babel/preset-react'] // ES5+ -> Old .Js | Tells babel we are using react
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s[ac]ss|css)$/i,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /  node_modules/,
                loader: "ts-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts','.js','.tsx','.jsx','.json'], // Importante, busca archivos por estos nombres al resolver modulos.
        modules: ['node_modules',path.resolve(__dirname,'src/ts/')],
        alias: {
            Components: 'Components/',
            Utils: 'Components/Utils/',
            Types: path.resolve(__dirname, 'custom.d.ts'),
            Styles: path.resolve(__dirname,"src/sass"),
            Assets: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/assets/')
        },
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'dist'), // Serve files from this directory
        compress: true,
        port: 3000
    },
}
```

So, the thing is that it's working nicely, it look the components and it builds without any errors.

But in VSC....

[image: Image Description]

`Cannot find module 'Components/Menu/Menu' or its corresponding type declarations.`

This is my tsconfig.json file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                         
    "module": "commonjs",                   
    "jsx": "react",                            
    "sourceMap": true,                    
    "outDir": "server/js/",
    "strict": true,          
    "noImplicitAny": true,                 
    "moduleResolution": "node",        
    "baseUrl": "src/",                     
    "paths": {
      "Components": ["ts/Components"],
      "Utils": ["ts/Components/Utils/"],
      "Types":["ts/custom.d.ts"],
      "Styles":["sass/"],
      "Assets":["assets/"]
    },                                     
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true,      
  "include": [
    "server/ts/*",
    "src/ts/**/*",
    "src/ts/custom.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

And My Folder Structure

[image]

*NOTE*: The project is not crashing, is going well, but it seems that Typescript cannot find the Module.

Maybe this is related to Typescript Module Resolution or something that I'm not considering?

Comment: You need to add a wildcard to map the directory contents: `"Components/*":  ["ts/Components/*"]`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I put it on the tsconfig.json but it didn't eliminates the error, Why did you put the `/*` ?

Comment: Now it goes, Thank you! @AluanHaddad

Comment: Because you are importing a module specifier located under `Components`